# Read and print the database in django html&sqlite3

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I'm just stuck.
How can I print the database in html on Django? I have "jegy.html" where I wanna print the jegy table, but else I said, I'm stuck.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'jegyrendeles/index.html', {})
def reg(request):
    return render(request, 'jegyrendeles/reg.html', {})
def jegy(request):
    return render(request, 'jegyrendeles/jegy.html', {})
def belep(request):
    return render(request, 'jegyrendeles/belep.html', {})
```

models.py
    from django.db import models

```
class Jegy(models.Model):
    j_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    j_nev = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    j_place = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'jegy'


class Rendeles(models.Model):
    r_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    j_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False)
    sz_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'rendeles'


class Szemely(models.Model):
    sz_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=True, null=False)
    sz_nev = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    sz_pw = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'szemely'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
from .models import Jegy

def jegy(request):
    data = Jegy.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'jegyrendeles/jegy.html', {'data':data})
```

and in `jegyrendeles/jegy.html`:

```
<table>
    {% for item in data %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ item.j_nev }}</td><td>{{ item.j_place }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: By the way, how it's work backward? If I want to insert datas from for example registration.html into Szemelyek table?

Comment: You should create a form and render it in registration.html. And in your view,  you can handle that form (model form is even easier) check if form.is_valid() then simply call form.save(). Here is the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Comment: Thank you. You save my night :D

Comment: No problem, glad we are having more django devs around ;)

Comment: Sorry one more last time I'll disturb you, so I made the form and work fine, but I don't find the place where I should write the form.save() , because the server say "TabError" nevermind where I place that command.

Comment: Just inside 'if form.is_valid():' however form.save() is available for ModelForm only. So instead, you might need to create instance using data available in form.cleaned_data, for e.g. instance = User(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],..) then instance.save()

Comment: TabError is also about indentation in python, pep8 recommends using 4 spaces instead of tabs. Your view should look like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: I can't finished jet , but thank you. I'm workin on it :)